# Unable to read XML from URL - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read XML using the API URL (i.e. I am trying to avoid downloading it) using the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class SampleXMLTest
{
    private void ReadXMLUsingURL_Test1()
    {
        log("#1");
        XmlDocument doc;
        XmlNamespaceManager ns;
        XmlNodeList nodes;

        // Create a new XmlDocument  
        doc = new XmlDocument();

        // Load data  
        doc.Load("http://apps.someurl.int/rest/collection/10000?expand=items&limit=100&offset=1400");

        log("#2");

        // Set up namespace manager for XPath  
        ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace(string.Empty, http://apps.someurl.int/rest/collection/10000?expand=items&limit=100&offset=1400");
        log("#3");

        // Get forecast with XPath  
        nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/collection/items", ns);  
        log("#4");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            log("<handle>:" + node.Attributes("handle").InnerText + vbtab + "<id>:" + node.Attributes("id").InnerText);
    }

    private void ReadXMLUsingURL_Test2()
    {
        log("#1");

        XmlNamespaceManager ns;
        XmlNodeList nodes;

        var m_strFilePath = "http://apps.someurl.int/rest/collection/10000?expand=items&limit=100&offset=1400";
        string xmlStr;

        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
        }

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

        log("#2");

        // Set up namespace manager for XPath  
        ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace(string.Empty, "http://apps.someurl.int/rest/collection/10000?expand=items");
        log("#3");

        // Get forecast with XPath  
        nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/collection/items", ns);
        log("#4");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            log("<handle>:" + node.Attributes["handle"].InnerText + vbtab + "<id>:" + node.Attributes["id"].InnerText);
    }


    private void log(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

The API/URL is accessible on the open internet, i.e. no authentication is required. However, the following error is being thrown when I try to run the above code. Could anyone advise how to resolve this, please?

```
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding the following code:

```
doc = new XmlDocument();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://apps.someurl.int/rest/collection/10000&limit=100&offset=100");
request.UserAgent = "My User Agent";

// Load data  
doc.Load(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

Issue is due to doc.Load not sending User-Agent, causing the server thinking it's a bot/script.

Comment: FYI Microsoft considers `HttpWebRequest` and `WebRequest` [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-6.0) and suggests using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) instead.